# add a text to navigation bar item

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I need to write a number on top of one of my navigation bar items ( on the shopping cart picture)
[image]

I tried to connect it with an outlet and using this code but it didn't
 work.

```
  self.BtnSabadNav.title = "3"
```

I also tried this code but it didn't work too.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.title = "fdf"
```

how should I do this?

Comment: You need to have a custom view with an image and a label.

Comment: Do you mean a badge?

Comment: yes. something like badge. I tried badge but it didn't show the badge neither @A.K.M

Comment: @RakeshaShastri I tried many ways but they didn't work. I used your way and it works. if you post your answer I will choose your answer as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to have a custom `UIView` which would contain a `UIImage` and `UILabel`. Then you need to set the custom view to the `UIBarBarButtonItem`.

```
let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: yourCustomView)
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButtonItem
```